# Uploading a File fails with Vaadin Spring PLupload-Addon

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, vaadin

If i want to upload a file with a specific widget/addon of Vaadin, im getting some warnings and the files does not be uploaded.

I don't have any idea, why this warning occurres. I was checking the whole addon and saw some JavaScript usage, which using that POST but i don't get why it throwing some warnings and doesn't work at all.

I checked the Addon without Spring integration and everything worked well.

This are the warnings:

```
2015-08-16_15:44:53.777 WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-08-16_15:44:53.777 WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-08-16_15:44:54.937 WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-08-16_15:44:54.938 WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-08-16_15:44:55.977 WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-08-16_15:44:55.977 WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-08-16_15:44:57.019 WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
2015-08-16_15:44:57.020 WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

My Code is the following, a simple init() with minimum of functionallity:

```
protected void init (VaadinRequest request){
    HorizontalLayout root = new HorizontalLayout();
    root.setSizeFull();
    setContent(root);
    setSizeFull();

    PluploadManager manager = new PluploadManager();
    manager.getUploader().setMaxFileSize("10mb");
    manager.getUploader().addFileUploadedListener(new Plupload.FileUploadedListener() {
        public void onFileUploaded(PluploadFile file) {
            Notification.show("I've just uploaded file: " + file.getName());
        }
    });

    manager.getUploader().addErrorListener(new Plupload.ErrorListener() {
        public void onError(PluploadError error) {
            Notification.show("There was an error: " + error.getMessage() + " (" + error.getType() + ")",
                    Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    });

    root.addComponent(manager);
}
```

Here are my dependencies inside the POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.beta3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>pl.exsio</groupId>
    <artifactId>plupload-vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Current Technolgies:

- Java 1.8
- Vaadin 7.5.3
- Spring Boot 1.3.0.M3 ( https://start.spring.io/ )
- Maven POM
- Vaadin Widget / Addon: PLupload Wrapper : ( https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/plupload-wrapper-for-vaadin-7x )

Comment: Where does it throw the errors/warnings? A stacktrace would be great too.

Comment: On the first "quotebox" is my console warnings output, i don't get any more information including the logs 
Additional i could upload the demo projekt, but in generell its a blank projekt of the Start Spring Projekt generator with the compiled widget/addon of Vaadin

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported out of the box.

The reason is that the URL `/pluploader-upload-action` is not being processed by Vaadin's servlet. The real URL of Vaadin's servlet is `/vaadinServlet`. Vaadin registers a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` with a `ServletForwardingController` on the root URL (by default) and /VAADIN.
For other URLs, you need to register them yourself.

Try this workaround.

In application.properties:

```
multipart.enabled=false
```

Add following configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class VaadinPluploadConfiguration {
  private static final String PLUPLOADER_URL = "/pluploader-upload-action";
  @Inject
  private Controller vaadinUiForwardingController;

  @Bean
  public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping vaadinForwardingHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1);
    Map<String, Object> urlMappings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    urlMappings.put(PLUPLOADER_URL, vaadinUiForwardingController);
    mapping.setUrlMap(urlMappings);
    return mapping;
  }
}
```

The multipart is disabled to allow Plupload add-on to process the multipart section that would otherwise be processed by Spring and would break the add-on.